# How to remove [] from print struct (swift4)

Tags: ios, struct, printing, label, swift4

My Code below prints a struct its how I want it expect for the []. I just want it removed. I circled the text in the photo below. I feel it has something to do with [Person].

```
      var contacts = [Person]()

@IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
    contacts.append(Person(name: a.text!,  phone: Int(c.text!)!))
    label.text = self.contacts.description
}}
struct Person {
var name: String
 var phone: Int}

extension Person: CustomStringConvertible {
var description: String {
return "\n\(name),\(phone)"
  }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing an array of Person ... not just a single person. So you get the square brackets:

```
bash-3.2$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.0 (swiftlang-900.0.63 clang-900.0.37). Type :help for assistance.
1> struct Person { var name: String; var phone: Int}
2> var contacts = [Person]()
contacts: [Person] = 0 values
3> contacts.append(Person(name: "john", phone: 911))
4> extension Person: CustomStringConvertible { public var description: String { return "\n\(name),\(phone)" }}
5> print(contacts)
[
john,911]
6> print(contacts[0])

john,911
```

I guess you could do something like this:

```
label.text = contacts.count == 0 ? "No people to contact" : contacts.map {$0.description}.joined(separator: "\n")
```

This will join up all the contacts into a single string with each contact separated by a newline.

Also, get rid of that initial newline in the CustomStringConvertible because now the `joined` supplies the separator for you.

Comment: Ok, I've joined up the contacts for you. Let me know if that works for you. (Then check my answer as your solution!)